# Getting the size of a minimized window

Tags: winapi

I never knew this, but apparently:

> By default, the system reduces a
>   minimized window to the size of its
>   taskbar button and moves the minimized
>   window to the taskbar. A restored
>   window is a window that has been
>   returned to its previous size and
>   position, that is, the size it was
>   before it was minimized or maximized.

In an application, we want to save the position/size of various windows at exit. This leads to a problem for minimized windows. Our solution is to restore all windows before running the save-state logic, but that just seems hacky. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**How about using [`GetWindowPlacement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633518.aspx)?**
That returns a [`WINDOWPLACEMENT` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632611.aspx) that contains information about the window's coordinates in the restored position.

Remember that (as Leo Davidson points out in the comments) that you must respect the difference between workspace and screen coordinates. As the `WINDOWPLACEMENT` documentation explains:

> The coordinates used in a
>   WINDOWPLACEMENT structure should be
>   used only by the GetWindowPlacement
>   and SetWindowPlacement functions.
>   Passing workspace coordinates to
>   functions which expect screen
>   coordinates (such as SetWindowPos)
>   will result in the window appearing in
>   the wrong location. For example, if
>   the taskbar is at the top of the
>   screen, saving window coordinates
>   using GetWindowPlacement and restoring
>   them using SetWindowPos causes the
>   window to appear to "creep" up the
>   screen.

Or, the simpler solution that I've no doubt used before is just to check if the window is minimized before saving the state, and if it is, skip saving any state information.

As far as explaining why a window changes its size when it gets minimized, [Raymond Chen's blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/02/10/370445.aspx) (and the linked entry as well) on the subject is mandatory reading. They don't really change to their taskbar button's size, but rather to a pre-defined size of 160x31. He explains that you can see this by minimizing a MDI child window into its parent—that's really its size.

Comment: +!, this is a job for GetWindowPlacement. Just be sure to only feed the values you get into SetWindowPlacement, because those two functions do not use the same coordinates as anything else (if you have taskbar/toolbar docked in unusual places, or multiple monitors with things docked on the common edges of them).

Comment: Current link to the blog article: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050210-00/?p=36483 (For some reason the editor doesn't want to recognise it as a link, otherwise I'd edit it into the post)

Answer (score 1):

Handle WM_SIZE message. If wParam is not SIZE_MAXIMIZED or SIZE_MINIMIZED, keep window size and position in some varibles. Use these variables when window is closed.