# Inverse of AdjustWindowRectEx()?

Tags: windows, winapi

The WinAPI function AdjustWindowRectEx() gives me the window rectangle based on a client rectangle and window style, without actually having a window handle:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632667(v=vs.85).aspx

Is there a function that can give me the client rectangle based on the window rectangle and style without a window handle?

My goal is to get the size of the restored client rectangle when minimized. I already know how to get the restored window rectangle:
[Getting the size of a minimized window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396109/getting-the-size-of-a-minimized-window)

Comment: Um, call `AdjustWindowRectEx` and take the negative of the result.

Comment: That did the trick! I guess I overlooked the obvious solution.