# minimize window driver selenium excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have searched a lot for a way to minimize the window of the driver in selenium for excel vba. I have found ways for Java and python and tried to adopt them but all my tries failed
I just found a way to maximize the window using

```
bot.Window.Maximize
```

But when trying to use Minimize I got an error

Again I am searching for excel vba as for selenium ...
Thanks advanced for help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK there is no method for this in VBA implementation (there is in Python for example). There are a number of ways to manipulate size and position e.g.

```
bot.Window.SetSize 0, 0
```

Or you can run headless

```
bot.AddArgument "--headless"
```

You might also try to:

1) Emulate Windows Key + Down

2) Write a javscript function that performs window.minimize() and async execute off the parent window

3) Capture your target co-ordinates by generating a [GetWindowPlacement](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?67260-API-Help-GetWindowPlacement) call along with implementing your own WINDOWPLACEMENT struct. Looks like gets ugly fast.

See also:

[Getting the size of a minimized window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396109/getting-the-size-of-a-minimized-window)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have tested both codes suggested but doesn't work properly

Comment: Headless means no browser visible. Set size can be used along with set position to place where you need. Otherwise, you know python which I think has a window minimize method.

Comment: I tested again the headless part and it is OK now. Thanks a lot

Comment: That argument has to be at the start. :-)

Comment: Driver.Window.SetSize 0, 0 just made the window smaller, without minimizing the browser to the taskbar.

Comment: Any way to make the window visible after initialized with Headless mode ?

Comment: I do not believe so @cyberponk

Answer (score 1):

`Driver.Window.SetSize 0, 0`
just made the window smaller, without minimizing the browser to the taskbar.

How to use `GetWindowPlacement` in selenium vba?

```
    'for vb6
Private Type POINTAPI
        x As Long
        y As Long
End Type
 
Private Type RECT
        Left As Long
        Top As Long
        Right As Long
        Bottom As Long
End Type
 
 
Private Type WINDOWPLACEMENT
        Length As Long
        flags As Long
        showCmd As Long
        ptMinPosition As POINTAPI
        ptMaxPosition As POINTAPI
        rcNormalPosition As RECT
End Type
 
Private Declare Function GetWindowPlacement Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, lpwndpl As WINDOWPLACEMENT) As Long
 
 
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim wp As WINDOWPLACEMENT
    wp.Length = Len(wp)
    GetWindowPlacement targetHandle, wp
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. What is the variable `targetHandle`? How to use with the selenium driver?

Comment: See my answer below "Minimize window by windows API"

Answer (score 1):

**Minimize window by windows API**

This is a workaround for Selenium VBA not having a working minimize window option.

```
''compiler constants
#If VBA7 Then
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function ShowWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal nCmdShow As Long) As Boolean
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As Long) As Long
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" (ByVal hWnd1 As LongPtr, ByVal hWnd2 As LongPtr, ByVal lpsz1 As String, ByVal lpsz2 As String) As Long
#Else
    Public Declare Function ShowWindow Lib "USER32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nCmdShow As Long) As Boolean
    Public Declare Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As Long) As Long
    Public Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" (ByVal hWnd1 As Long, ByVal hWnd2 As Long, ByVal lpsz1 As String, ByVal lpsz2 As String) As Long
#End If

    Dim hwnd As Long
    Dim Botwindowtitle As String
    bot.Start    
    Botwindowtitle = bot.Window.Title
    hwnd = GetAllWindowHandles(Botwindowtitle)
    Call ShowWindow(hwnd, 7) 'Show the window minimized (SW_SHOWMINNOACTIVE = 7) http://www.jasinskionline.com/windowsapi/ref/s/showwindow.html
     bot.Get "https://www.google.com/"



Private Function GetAllWindowHandles(partialName As String) As Long
    Dim hwnd As Long, lngRet As Long
    Dim strText As String
    Dim hWndTemp As Long
    hwnd = FindWindowEx(0&, 0&, vbNullString, vbNullString)

Do While hwnd <> 0
        strText = String$(100, Chr$(0))
        lngRet = GetWindowText(hwnd, strText, 100)

        If InStr(1, strText, partialName, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            Debug.Print "Window Handle:" & hwnd & vbNewLine & _
                        "Window title:" & Left$(strText, lngRet) & vbNewLine & _
                        "----------------------"
            hWndTemp = hwnd
            GetAllWindowHandles = hWndTemp
        End If

        '~~> Find next window
        hwnd = FindWindowEx(0&, hwnd, vbNullString, vbNullString)
Loop
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have tested the code but the browser isn't minimized.

Comment: It seems to get the Handle by caption only with  the function GetAllWindowHandles . 
Try it now.

Comment: The same problem. The code works but the window is not minimized.

Comment: Do you get  hwnd<>0 ? if this is true try Call ShowWindow(hwnd, 11). I tried it and it did minimize.

Comment: I tried `Call ShowWindow(hwnd, 11)` and it sent the browser window to the back but was not minimized.

Comment: maybe  Call ShowWindow(hwnd, 6) or Call ShowWindow(hwnd, 2)? See parameters: http://www.jasinskionline.com/windowsapi/ref/s/showwindow.html

Comment: I tried 6 and the same as 11 sent the window to the back but not minimized. And as for 2 doesn't display any influence.

Comment: Call ShowWindow(hwnd, 0) SW_HIDE = 0 Hide the window

Comment: I tried this line and worked `hwnd = GetAllWindowHandles("data:, - Google Chrome")` as it seems the `Botwindowtitle = bot.Window.Title` returns empty string.