# Hide browser bot during code execution display at end selenium VBA

Tags: vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to find a way that enables me to hide the driver (bot) of the selenium in VBA during the execution of the code and display it at end
I can hide it using this line

```
bot.AddArgument "--headless"
```

But how I restore it?

Answer (score 3):

**No**, it won't be possible to make Chrome operate initially in *headless* mode  and then switch back to normal mode within the same session.

When you configure an instance of a *WebDriver* with `Options()` to span a new *Browsing Context* the configuration gets *baked* within the *driver* executable which will persist for the lifetime of the *WebDriver* and being **uneditable**. So you can't modify/add any existing/new *configuration* through `Options()` class to the *WebDriver* instance which is currently in execution.

Even if you are able to extract the *Driver* and *Session* attributes e.g. ***Session ID***, ***Cookies***, ***UserAgent*** and other session attributes from the already initiated *Driver* and *Browsing Session* still you won't be able to change the set of attributes of the *Driver*.
You can find more details in these discussions:

- [How to set selenium webdriver from headless mode to normal mode within the same session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54721676/how-to-set-selenium-webdriver-from-headless-mode-to-normal-mode-within-the-same/54722252#54722252)
- [Change ChromeOptions in an existing webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53023853/change-chromeoptions-in-an-existing-webdriver/53025100#53025100)
- [How do I make Chrome Headless after I login manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53296228/how-do-i-make-chrome-headless-after-i-login-manually/53296911#53296911)

Credits to [undetected Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7429447/undetected-selenium)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is it possible to minimize the bot window as I tried a lot and failed as for this point. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53902049/

Comment: 1) I'm not really familiar with VBA Selenium so I can help with issues common to all the Selenium bindings, not specific to VBA 2) I see you got several answers there, they are looking good

Comment: I can't get it to work properly. I really tried a lot but no real way ro do that.

Comment: Are you talking about minimizing the window?

Comment: Yes about minimizing the window or if it is impossible to hide the bot and display it. Is it possible to use WIndows API to do such a trick?

Comment: I don't know, I'm sorry

Comment: Some time ago I also tried to hide it and I didn't find a solution.
I put the window in the corner and it's small, but I thought it was better to just minimize it and leave it like that without hide browser.